# WSO2 ESB - How does Passthrough handle empty payloads

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I would like to know if the WSO2 ESB stalls whenever consecutive ping requests are made (without any payload). Is there a way to capture such scenario.

Comment: Which version are you using?  How exactly are you doing these ping requests so others can help you by recreating the problem themselves.  Do you have an HTTP endpoint and what's the sequence behind it?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB does not stall when the incoming payload is empty. It will internally represent it as a soap envelope with an empty body.